# A question about the canonical maps $H^i(X,\mathcal{F}) \to H^i(X,sh(\mathcal{F}))$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, exact-sequence

In Algebraic Geometry Ⅱ by Mumford and Oda, page 294,
some reasonable cases where the long exact cohomology sequences
for sheaves holds are being analyzed.

For example, if we could prove

> ($*$)for all presheaves $\mathcal{F}$, the canonical maps
> $H^i(X,\mathcal{F}) \to H^i(X,sh(\mathcal{F}))$ are isomorphisms.

then the long exact sequences holds.

Then the authors said
[image]

Maybe applying twice the long exact sequence means applying to the two short exact sequences in the diagram to show the morphisms induced by $\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}'$ and $\mathcal{F}' \to sh \mathcal{F}$ are isomorphism. But I can't see why we ($**$) could imply ($*$). Could you give me some help? Thanks!

Comment: What does $H^i$ even mean for a presheaf here?

Comment: @ZhenLin $\mathcal{F}$ is a presheaf of abelian groups, 
and $H^i(X,\mathcal{F}) = \varinjlim_{\mathcal{U}} H^i(\mathcal{U},\mathcal{F}) $ is the $i$th Cech cohomology group.

Comment: Well, that is the right derived functor of the plus construction, so you get a long exact sequence as usual. Doing the plus construction twice gives you the associated sheaf.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks, I forget that sheafification is a exact functor, now I see.